# Confused by derivative of wave function

Tags: partial-derivative, differential

The setup is as follows: $u=f(x-ct)$ where $f$ is some arbitrary function and $x-ct$ is its argument.

Differentiation of $u$ yields:
$$du = f'dx-cf'dt$$

It's completely unclear to me with respect to what variable the expression above is being differentiated.

If $x$ and $t$ in turn were functions of the same variable then this would make more sense to me, but they are not ($x$ is space and $t$ is time).

I can provide more context if needed - it's from an acoustics textbook.

Comment: It's both. They did the $dx$ term first then the $dt$ term second. The notation is a little non-standard but if you're working with differentials rather than derivatives it works.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. So is the expression the same as $$du=df-cdf$$? where the "denominators" of the differential operators are being "cancelled" by multiplying by $dx$ and $dt$ respectively? If so, what would be the original expression on the LHS? $\frac{du}{dtdx}$?

Comment: +1 for a pretty good first question. Remember that 4du$ is the [total differential](https://www.math.unl.edu/~tshores1/Public/Math208F07/Math208DifferentialsHandout.pdf) which can be expressed as a sum of its partial derivatives as shown in the given link.

Comment: You can't really treat them like fractions. They're differentials. It's $du = \frac{du}{dx} dx -c \frac{du}{dt} dt$ if you expand out the primes.

Comment: What is a function of what? Is $\;x\;$ a function of $\;t\;$ or the other way around? Differentiation of $\;u\;$ with respect to what?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and in particular for the handout. It is looking much clearer to me now. In response to your question @DonAntonio $x$ and $t$ are independent of each other. That was part of the reason for my initial confusion.

Comment: You didn't specify differentiation of $\;u\;$ WRT WHAT...

Comment: You'll have to take that up with the author of the book that the formula is written in! As other commenters have mentioned the variable wrt which it's being integrated doesn't appear because the expression is in differential form.